# Incorrect positions in deferred shading in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl, deferred-rendering, tessellation

I'm currently working on a Deferred shading project in DirectX. I noticed weird lighting when I create the final image;

[image]

With this light ray constantly shining from the top left. I looked at my gbuffers and noticed that my position only seems to take the UV coordinates of the screen (but flipped?) where objects are located.

[image: Position, Normal, Diffuse and Render result]

Uv coordinate map for reference

[image]

This becomes way more apparent when I try to apply shadow mapping.

[image]

The answer is probably really easy, but I am staring myself blind at my code to find what's wrong. I'm posting my shader codes below, sorry if its a lot, I have implemented a working tesselator as well, and I think the problem either lies in the domain or pixelshader.

**Vertex shader**

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

VertexShaderOutput DeferredVertexShader(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    output.position = input.position;
    output.texcoord = input.texcoord;
    output.normal = input.normal;

    return output;
}
```

**Hull shader**

```
cbuffer TessellationBuffer
{
    matrix world;
    float3 CamPos;
    float padding;
};

struct HullShaderInput
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct ConstantOutput
{
    float edges[3] : SV_TessFactor;
    float inside   : SV_InsideTessFactor;
};

struct HullShaderOutput
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;

};

// PATCH OUTPUT FUNCTION

ConstantOutput PatchConstantFunction(InputPatch<HullShaderInput, 3> inputPatch, uint patchId : SV_PrimitiveID)
{
    ConstantOutput output;
    float3 center = (inputPatch[0].position + inputPatch[1].position + inputPatch[2].position) / 3.0f;
    float3 centerW = mul(float4(center, 1.0f), world).xyz;

    const float d = distance(centerW, CamPos);
    const float d0 = 0.01f;
    const float d1 = 10.0f;

    float tessellationAmount = 12.0f * saturate((d1 - d) / (d1 - d0)) + 1;

    output.edges[0] = tessellationAmount;
    output.edges[1] = tessellationAmount;
    output.edges[2] = tessellationAmount;
    output.inside = tessellationAmount;

    return output;
}

// Hull shader
[domain("tri")]
[partitioning("integer")]
[outputtopology("triangle_cw")]
[outputcontrolpoints(3)]
[patchconstantfunc("PatchConstantFunction")]

HullShaderOutput DeferredHullShader(InputPatch<HullShaderInput, 3> patch, uint pointId : SV_OutputControlPointID, uint patchId : SV_PrimitiveID)
{
    HullShaderOutput output;

    output.position = patch[pointId].position;
    output.texcoord = patch[pointId].texcoord;
    output.normal = patch[pointId].normal;

    return output;
}
```

**Domain shader**

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    matrix world;
    matrix view;
    matrix proj;
};

struct ConstantOutput
{
    float edges[3] : SV_TessFactor;
    float inside   : SV_InsideTessFactor;
};

struct DomainShaderInput
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct DomainShaderOutput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

// DOMAIN SHADER

[domain("tri")]

DomainShaderOutput DeferredDomainShader(ConstantOutput input, const OutputPatch<DomainShaderInput, 3> patch, float3 barycentric : SV_DomainLocation)
{
    float4 worldPos;
    float3 vertexPosition, flatPosition;
    DomainShaderOutput output;

    output.texcoord = barycentric.x * patch[0].texcoord + barycentric.y * patch[1].texcoord + barycentric.z * patch[2].texcoord;
    output.normal = barycentric.x * patch[0].normal + barycentric.y * patch[1].normal + barycentric.z * patch[2].normal;

    vertexPosition = barycentric.x * patch[0].position + barycentric.y * patch[1].position + barycentric.z * patch[2].position;

    float3 vecProj0 = dot(patch[0].position - vertexPosition, patch[0].normal) * patch[0].normal;
    float3 vecProj1 = dot(patch[1].position - vertexPosition, patch[1].normal) * patch[1].normal;
    float3 vecProj2 = dot(patch[2].position - vertexPosition, patch[2].normal) * patch[2].normal;

    float3 vecOffset = barycentric.x * vecProj0 + barycentric.y * vecProj1 + barycentric.z * vecProj2;

    vertexPosition += 0.5f * vecOffset;

    worldPos = mul(vertexPosition, world);

    output.position = mul(float4(vertexPosition, 1.0f), world);
    output.position = mul(output.position, view);
    output.position = mul(output.position, proj);

    output.normal = mul(output.normal, (float3x3)world);
    output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

    return output;
}
```

**Pixel shader**

```
Texture2D diffuseTexture : register(t0);
Texture2D specularTexture : register(t1);
Texture2D ambientTexture : register(t2);

SamplerState sampleTypeWrap : register(s0);

cbuffer MaterialBuffer
{
    float specularPower;
    float3 pad3;
};

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct PixelShaderOutput
{
    float4 position : SV_Target0;
    float4 normal   : SV_Target1;
    float4 diffuse  : SV_Target2;
    float4 specular : SV_Target3;
    float4 ambient  : SV_Target4;
};

PixelShaderOutput DeferredPixelShader(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    PixelShaderOutput output;
    output.position = input.position;
    output.position.w = 1.0f;

    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    output.normal = float4(input.normal, 1.0f);
    output.diffuse = diffuseTexture.Sample(sampleTypeWrap, input.texcoord);
    output.specular = specularTexture.Sample(sampleTypeWrap, input.texcoord);
    output.ambient = ambientTexture.Sample(sampleTypeWrap, input.texcoord);
    output.specular.w = specularPower;

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Your gbuffer position is in screen space, to apply shading you want either view space or world space position, so either you add a channel for that from the domain shader to the pixel shader, or more commonly you can reconstruct world position from depth buffer.

Comment: @mrvux Ok but I think I do that in my compute shader (which acts as the light pass):  <br/>
  <br/>
`float4x4 lightView = lBuffer[index].lightView;
float4x4 lightProj = lBuffer[index].lightProj;

float4 lightViewPos = mul(float4(pos, 1.0f), lightView);
lightViewPos = mul(lightViewPos, lightProj);
float2 projUV;

projUV.x = lightViewPos.x / lightViewPos.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;
projUV.y = -lightViewPos.y / lightViewPos.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;`

lBuffer holds all the lights information, and pos is a float3 from the position gBuffer

Comment: @mrvux weird formatting for the code, but basically I take pos which is a float3 from the position gbuffer and multiplied it with the view and proj matrix from the lights that I loop through, or is this something completely else?

Comment: Well that's correct except your position from the gbuffer is in the wrong space (it needs to be in world space to work)

Comment: @mrvux sorry for being completely dense, but I'm trying to wrap my head around the transformation... If I understand right, to get the position into world space, I would need to multiply it by the inverse of the view, then projection, lastly world matrix. But wouldn't that render the calculations I make in the domain shader (where I multiply the vertexPosition by world, view and proj) obsolete?

Comment: @mrvux so yeah, learnt a bit more in these two months and decided to tackle this again. My problem was that I didn't understand how SV_position changed the coordinates, so now I have a second position channel like you suggested and I send it before doing any matrix calculations so it is still in world coordinates. I still think it looks weird, and my shadowmapping calculations doesnt work. Position gBuffer now:
https://imgur.com/a/zEaczyG